# Facebook Connect Auto Login for my website

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

My requirement is that once the user signs in with his Facebook account into my website, from next time onwards he/she should automatically get logged into my website unless he/she has logged out.

Currently I am able to allow users to sign in using Facebook account, but the problem is with the auto login.

My Code is as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Facebook login</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
 </head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table align="center">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="color: #33ccff; font-size: large; font-   weight: bold; text-transform: capitalize;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="margin-top: 350px;">
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            // Load the SDK Asynchronously 
                            (function (d) {
                                var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                                if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
                                js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                                ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
                            }(document));

                            // Init the SDK upon load
                            window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                                FB.init({
                                    appId: 'xxxxxxxx', // App ID 
                                    channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname +   '/channel', // Path to your Channel File 
                                    status: true, // check login status 
                                    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session 
                                    xfbml: true  // parse XFBML 
                                });

                                // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events 
                                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {

                                    if (response.authResponse) {

                                        // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook 
                                        FB.api('/me', function (me) {
                                            if (me.name) {
                                                document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
                                                document.getElementById('UserEmail').innerHTML = me.email;
                                                document.getElementById('UserGender').innerHTML = me.gender;
                                                document.getElementById('AccessToken').innerHTML = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                                                getPhoto();
                                            }
                                        })
                                        document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
                                        document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
                                    } else {
                                        // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook 
                                        document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
                                        document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
                                    }
                                });
                                $("#auth-logoutlink").click(function () { FB.logout(function () { window.location.reload(); }); });


                                function getPhoto() {
                                    FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function (response) {

                                        var str = "<br/> <img src='" + response.data.url + "'/>";

                                        document.getElementById("ProfilePic").innerHTML = str;

                                    });
                                }
                            }

                        </script>
                        <h1>Facebook Integration with Aspnet Example</h1>
                        <div id="auth-status">
                            <div id="auth-loggedout">
                                <div autologoutlink="true" class="fb-login-button" scope="email,user_checkins">
                                    Login with Facebook
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="auth-loggedin" style="display: none;">
                                Hi, <span id="auth-displayname">Welcome to Toqsoft </span>(<a href="#" id="auth-logoutlink">Signout</a>)
                                <div id="ProfilePic">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <b>Email :</b><span id="UserEmail"></span><br />
                                    <b>Gender :</b><span id="UserGender"></span><br />
                                    <b>AccessToken :</b><span id="AccessToken"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div id="AccessToken1">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are not even logging in the user into facebook. You can use the following button in order to allow the user to login:

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

Then in the `checkLoginState` callback, call `FB.getLoginStatus`:

```
function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
       // do stuff
    });
}
```

This should give you an access_token and an app_scoped user_id, if the `response.status` is  `connected`.

This is actually all pretty well documented here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1

Comment: well, you can also use FB.login with a custom button instead of the social plugin, but getLoginStatus is definitely worth it. +1 for you, sir :)